# How to stop a loop triggered by tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and even more so to tkinter, and I decided to try to create a start and stop button for an infinite loop through Tkinter. Unfortunately, once I click start, it won't allow me to click stop. The start button remains indented, and I assume this is because the function it triggered is still running. How can I make this 2nd button stop the code?

```
import tkinter

def loop():
    global stop
    stop = False
    while True:
        if stop == True:
            break
        #The repeating code
def start():
    loop()
def stop():
    global stop
    stop = True

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Loop")
startButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Start", command = start)
stopButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Pause", command = stop)
startButton.pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `while True`. Long story short, `Tk()` has it's own event loop. So, whenever you call some long running process it blocks this event loop and you can't do anything. You should probably use `after`

I avoided using `global` here by just giving an attribute to `window`.

e.g. -

```
import tkinter

def stop():

    window.poll = False

def loop():

    if window.poll:
        print("Polling")
        window.after(100, loop)
    else:
        print("Stopped long running process.")

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.poll = True
window.title("Loop")
startButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Start", command = loop)
stopButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Pause", command = stop)
startButton.pack()
stopButton.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense for the most part. I'm assuming the arguments for after are in the form of after(wait-time, function)?

Comment: Yes, the time is in milliseconds. So, 1000 = 1 second.

Comment: This works, however, since loop is being recursively called, won't you get a stack overflow error after maxing out at Python's 999 max depth?

Comment: @ReidBarber No. Tkinter is threaded and this just adds another item to the threads events to process. Although there is a problem in the code if you want to continously be able to click "Start", but it's easy enough to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! @Pythonista, It works for me stopping a for loop in the tkinter. But it is likely not an effective way to do that because the frame was stuck after I pressed the stop button as demonstrated below with part of script:                                               `

```
    def start_scan(self):    
        self.voltage_scan(
                      self.start.get(),
                      self.stop.get(),
                      self.step.get(),
                      self.delay.get()
                      
                      )       
                          
    def start_butt(self): 
    
        if self.poll:
            self.start_scan()
            
    def stop_butt(self):
        self.poll = False

    def voltage_scan(self, start, stop, step, delay):
        
        
        def make_plot():
            plt.scatter(mvol,mcurr)
            plt.xlabel('Voltage / V', fontsize = 12)
            plt.ylabel('Current / A', fontsize = 12)
            plt.tight_layout()
            
        if start < stop:
            stop = stop + 1
     
            
            plt.ion()  # enable interactivity
            fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,3.5), dpi = 100)
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
            curr  = 0
            mvol = []
            mcurr = []
            
            for vol in range(start, stop, step):
                if self.poll:
                    mvol.append(vol)
                    #time.sleep(1 / delay)
                    self.after(1000*delay)  # 1 second delay
                    curr += 1
                    mcurr.append(curr)
                    #print(vol, curr)
                    drawnow(make_plot)
                else:
                    break
```

`

[image: Wigets and liveplot after stoppig]

There might be better way to do that. or at least there would be a way to refresh the frame without closing the program. bcz I have to restart the program after evrytime I press the stop button.